# Passing data from Javascript MVC controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I'm really new to jQuery and Charts. This is my script, it works fine. It gives me the id of the checkboxes selected by the user. I have a Chart action in my controller which also works fine, but it creates a chart using all my values. I want it to create a chart based on the selected values that are in my script. I don't know how to pass the selected values to my controller.

```
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
$(function ()
{
    function getValueUsingClass() {
        /* declare an checkbox array */
        var chkArray = [];

        /* look for all checkboes that have a class 'chk' attached to it and check if it was checked */
        $(".chk:checked").each(function () {
            chkArray.push($(this).val());
        });

        /* we join the array separated by the comma */
        var selected = chkArray.join(",") + ",";

        /* check if there is selected checkboxes, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */
        if (selected.length > 1)
        {
            alert("You have selected " + selected);
        }
         else
         {
            alert("Please check at least one of the checkbox");
         }        
    }

    $("#Charter").click(function () {
        getValueUsingClass();
    });
});
```

Comment: your action method is not taking any parameters. what data are you trying to send ?

Comment: i'm trying to send the values in arrar chkArray to my Charter Action in my controller

Comment: Instaed of iterating etc, simpler is extract selected checkbox by: $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'). For communication you can use ajax and in your controller return JSON. then in highcharts creation use $.getJSON() and load data / options

Comment: i'm sorry , i'm new to this and i kind of understand what you're saying but i'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Return the data you want in your js function after populating the variable using `return selected;` then send it back by posting a form or using ajax.

Bind your data to an element on your View page, for example:

```
<input name="foo" id="yourId" value="bar" />
```

then modify it's value:

```
$('#foo').val(getValueUsingClass());
```

and pass the model back by posting your form to your controller.

If you wish to send data to your controller async then you can look into [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to call your controller method within `getValueUsingClass()`.

It would probably look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/YourControllerName/Chart",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { arr: chkArray }, 
    success: function () {
        // do things upon success
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error!");
    }
});
```

That is, providing your Controller action has a parameter named `arr`, because json maps `chkArray` to it once it is passed to the Controller.